# Split large file into chunks and delete original?

Tags: macos, split, large-files

I'm having trouble with a large text file (30GB)

I would like to create smaller files from it (5GB lets say)

But sadly I don't have no more storage (only ~10G is available).

**This line:**

```
split -b 5g "file.txt" "file.txt."
```

Leaves the original file in place, meaning I will end up with 60 GB in total. Which is more than I actually have free left in my pc.

How could I run a code that does the same, while not keeping the original file?

Comment: Note that `split -b` works on bytes: it will split a few lines across two files. From the man page, `split -c` keeps any whole lines together.

Comment: If you have a back-up device, you must surely have enough free space on there, because you would need it for your next complete backup. If you don't have a back-up device, buy one. Today! It will be about 20 bucks.

Answer (score 2):

On a file system having only ***~1.03G*** of free-disk-space;
splitting a file ***~9.3G*** of size.

we are going to split this file into 10 small files each about ***1G*** of size.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    tail -c 1G bigfile >split_file_$i && truncate -s -1G bigfile;
done
```

this almost use ***1G*** of free-disk space from ***~1.03G*** available and only ***~30M*** remaining each time! (I'm on test environment); of course you need adjust split size according to your available free-disk-space and ***don't go to use all of that available space!***, use for example up-to 80% of it.

---

to rejoin back into one file:

```
for file in split_file_{10..1}; do
    cat "$file" >>bigfile_joined && rm "$file"; 
done
```

Comment: A minor optimisation: the first section of the original file (i.e. the last part to be processed) does not need to be copied, as it has already been truncated nine times: renaming it would suffice. With 10 sections, that is only a 10% improvement (less if the size division is unequal). With two or three sections, it may be a significant improvement. It also avoids having to remove the (now zero-sized) bigfile.